# Which of these loops are more efficient?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I have these three collections in Java:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(6000);
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(6000);
ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(6000);
```

Which is more efficient to loop through and set to 0?

```
for(int i =0; i < rHist.size(); i++) {
    list1.set[i] = 0;
    list2.set[i] = 0;
    list3.set[i] = 0;
}
```

Or this?

```
for (int n : list1) {
    n = 0;
}


for (int n : list2) {
    n = 0;
}


for (int n : list3) {
    n = 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Variant 1) Does not compile; Variant 2) does not set the List's contents to zero.

Comment: Don't think about micro-optimizations. They don't matter. Start by making your code compilable, then correct.

Comment: oops, sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, both of the variants do not reach the goal you stated. That being said, better look to write readable, understandable and short code and refrain to the methods given in the Collections API. Something like that fills your list with 6000 copies of zeros:

```
List<Integer> list = Collections.nCopies(6000, 0);
```

If you need to mutate the list afterwards, you need to wrap it in a modifiable List like so:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(6000, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better because you are looping one time instead of three if you put the size to 6000 in the loop, and the set should look like this `list1.set(i,0)` instead of `list1[i]=0`

if you decompiled both them uisng `javap -c "appname"` lets assume that they are under the main, you can see your self whats happening